# How to print the number in a particular format in a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write 001 as 01 but I am not able to do that.

I used `zfill` and `rjust` but the answer keeps coming as 001.

I also used `'{:0>2}'.format('001')` but it gives 001 only not 01.

Comment: Note that what you are trying to format (`'001'`) is already a string, not a number.

Comment: Can you clarify the entire set of constraints? How would that code have to write ``0001`` or ``01`` or ``1`` or ``101``, for example? If you have only one input and one output, just returning that output regardless of input is the simplest approach otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just take off the first character

```
print("001"[1:])
```